# Given function $g$ continuous in line $[0,\infty)$...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

Given function $g$ continuous in line $[0,\infty)$, positive and strongly increasing that upholds $\lim_{t\to\infty}  g(t) = L$.
Calculate the limit: 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_1^2 g(nx) \, dx.
$$

At the moment what I think that I should do is swap the $g(nx)$ with $L$ as it approaches infinity but from there on I am just not sure whats my next step is.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int\limits_1^2 g(nx) dx = \int\limits_1^2 \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} g(nx)dx = \int\limits_1^2 L dx = L . $$

Different approach. 
$$ g(n) =\int\limits_1^2g(n)dx\leq \int\limits_1^2 g(nx) dx \leq \int\limits_1^2 g(2n) dx = g(2n) $$
By the squezee theorem, we get the result.

Comment: Thanks alot! that's a great approach

Comment: Adam, what does it mean that you were able to answer without using MCT? Did you perhaps reinvent the wheel by not using MCT since the proof of MCT uses what you did? Or could MCT perhaps be proved by what you did in a way that it hasn't been proven before? Or do the assumptions of this case differ from the assumptions of MCT? Also, did you use continuity on [0,\infty) in different approach? Could this continuity assumption be weakened?

Comment: @BCLC Monotonicity is irrelevant.

Comment: We can replace the assumption about continuity with the assumption of the function being measurable.

Comment: Not everyone is aware about MCT, so i thought about giving the solution that doesn't use (at least directly) this theorem.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks! It's good to know I asked a good question for a change.

Comment: @Adam I was asking about the philosophical (proof-theoretic?) implications. You are able to answer without using MCT. So what gives? It seems the possibilities are 1. monotonicity is irrelevant 2. you are reinventing the wheel 3. you discovered a new proof of MCT.

Comment: MCT deals with integrals on any measurable set. This get's a lot simpler when the set is an interval. Monotonicity wouldn't be irrelevant if we assumed the function isn't continues, but just measurable.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! ^-^

Comment: Dear downvoter, are you @Did?

Comment: @Adam Huh? The argument I posted never uses contiinuity, except implicitly, to guarantee the integrals exist. If you assume just measurability _exactly_ the same argument works.

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with monotonicity. If $g$ is continuous and $\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t)=L$ then $$g(nt)\to L\quad(n\to\infty)$$*uniformly* for  $t\in[1,2]$, hence $\int_1^2 g(nt)\,dt\to L$.

Regarding a comment: Monotonicty is still irrelevant even if we assume $g$ is just measurable instead of continuous. If $g$ is measurable and $\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t)=L$ then the argument above applies without change to show $\int_1^2g(nt)\,dt\to L$.

**Utterly and Completely Trivial Obvious Details:** Suppose $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so $|g(t)-L|<\epsilon$ for every $t>N$. Now if $n>N$ it follows that $|g(nt)-L|<\epsilon$ for every $t\in[1,2]$, since $nt>N$; this says precisely that $g(nt)\to L$ uniformly on $[1,2]$. Nothing to do with monotonicity *or* continuity.