# $g$ is monotonic strictly increasing, continuous in $ [0,\infty)$ and positive function.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, indefinite-integrals

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} g(t)=L $$
 $g$ is monotonic strictly increasing, continuous in $ [0,\infty)$ and positive function.

I need to find : 
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int^2_1 g (nx) \,\mathrm{d}x  $$

I have started with: 
 $|g(t)-L|<\epsilon\>$

$L-\epsilon\>$$=<$$g(t)$$<=$$L+\epsilon\>$

$\int^2_1 (L-\epsilon\>) \,\mathrm{d}x$$=<$$\int^2_1 g (nx) \,\mathrm{d}x$$<=$$\int^2_1 (L+\epsilon\>) \,\mathrm{d}x$

I'm not sure if I'm in the right direction ...

Comment: You're given $g$ is **monotonic** so by the **monotonic** convergence theorem:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int^2_1 g (nx) \,\mathrm{d}x  $$  
$$= \int^2_1 \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  g (nx) \,\mathrm{d}x  $$  
$$= \int^2_1 \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  g (n) \,\mathrm{d}x  $$  
$$= \int^2_1 L \mathrm{d}x  $$

Comment: Your're done! The inequality $\int^2_1 (L-\epsilon\>) \,\mathrm{d}x$$=<$$\int^2_1 g (nx) \,\mathrm{d}x$$<=$$\int^2_1 (L+\epsilon\>) \,\mathrm{d}x$ says exactly $L-\epsilon\le\int^2_1 g (nx) \le L+\epsilon$, or $|L-\int_1^2 g(nt)\,dt|\le\epsilon$.

Answer (score -1):

You have using integral by substitution with $u = nx$:
$$l_n = \int^2_1 g (nx) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{n} \int_n^{2n} g (u) \,\mathrm{d}u $$

As $g$ is supposed to be strictly increasing, you have for $u \in [n, 2n]$ $g(n) \le g(u) \le g(2n)$. Therefore
$$g(n) \le l_n \le g(2n)$$ by taking the integral of those inequalities over $[n,2n]$.

Knowing the hypothesis on $g$, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ exists (it can be $\infty$). Naming this limit $L$, you get
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} l_n = L$$

Comment: How did you get the 'therefore' please? Seems like mean value theorem, extreme value theorem, intermediate value theorem or something simple, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @BCLC I added some details.

Comment: @hemi substitution? $u=nx$ so $du/n=dx$

Comment: Thanks mathcounterexamples.net! I actually thought of using monotonic convergence is $g$ is monotonic. What does it mean that you were able to answer without using MCT? Did you perhaps reinvent the wheel by not using MCT since the proof of MCT uses what you did? Or could MCT perhaps be proved by what you did in a way that it hasn't been proven before? Or do the assumptions of this case differ from the assumptions of MCT? Also, did you use continuity on [0,\infty)? Could this be weakened?

Comment: monotonicity is irrelevant! :O [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2796993/140308)